# How to install Tizen 4/5 emulators on macOS?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

Could you please advise how to install Tizen 4, 5 emulators on my macOS machine?

I have the latest SDK which is available with Tizen Studio 4.1.1

What I have tried to do:

1. To find a public image of the Tizen 5 and add it via emulator manager - I didn't find the image
2. Install older SDK from the archive and install it via the package manager - older SDKs and IDE's didn't work (the app is corrupted error)

I'm using macOS Catalina (10.15.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to install Tizen tv 5.5 (or less) emulators on modern 4.1.1 setup:

1. Download the emulator from archive https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/tools/tv-extension/archive.html
2. Unzip the downloaded file and all zip files in the binary folder (unzip *.zip)
3. find folder `platforms/tizen-5.5/tv-samsung` and move the only that folder into `tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-5.5/tv-samsung`

Comment: Some remarks: 1. All the ZIP files should be extracted in the same directory since many of them contain files in similar directories needed for the older emulators to work properly 2. To make remote debugging work on Tizen 5 or older, Chrome version 63 must be used on dev computer (Chrome 64 broke old Dev tools). I use a Portable Chrome 63 version in parallel. Check the new port Tizen Studio mapped (available in build log and popuped non functional Dev tools window) and navigate to localhost:[port number] in Chrome 63 and select your app

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to install an old emulator is:

- Download the TV Extension Image, of the TV version you want and your OS from: [Archive > TV Extension for Tizen SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/tools/tv-extension/archive.html).
- Go in Tizen Studio to Tools > Package Manager. Then follow the instructions detailed in [Installing TV SDK > Installing Required Extensions](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/installing-tv-sdk.html#Installing-Required-Extensions), to install the SDK you downloaded, from a local file (it's at the end of the page).
- Go in Tizen Studio to Tools > Emulator Manager, then follow the instructions detailed in [TV Emulator > Creating Emulator Instances](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-emulator.html), and when creating a new emulator, you should be able to find the old emulator image you just installed.

Comment: This is the more updated way.  However make sure you uninstall the original emulator you had, or you may get an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tested it with TS 4.1.1 version.
First, I installed Mobile 5.0 via the package-manger
Path) ~/tizen-studio/package-manager/package-manager.bin
Second, I can see the installed mobile 5.0 emulator on the emulator manager.
Last, I can launch the 5.0 emulator on the Catalina os.

Could you follow the above steps?
Thanks

Comment: You were able to launch a 5.0 TV, right?